# Need to write tests to methods that returns a constant value?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing

I'm not deeply familiar with testing techniques, so I need help with such problem:
For example, three classes (C1 C2 C3 ) implements interface I

```
class I
{
  char get_Char() const = 0;
} 

C1::get_Char() const { return 'a' };
C2::get_Char() const { return 'b' };
C3::get_Char() const { return 'c' };
```

Should I test this method in my tests?

I think - yes, but I can't find confirmation or refutation of my gues. Can you point me to good theory about what need to test and what not.

Comment: I don't have any theory to state, so I'm leaving this as a comment.  But typically, when you test, you test *something*.  What happens if the inputs change?  What happens in each possible logical branch?  Is the return value calculated correctly?  In your case, you have no inputs, no logical branches, and no chance the return value can be altered.  I see nothing to test, though I'm sure others will tell you and me both how I'm wrong.

Comment: You do not test "just because you can". You test either to verify your code, or as a help for mantaining it in future, or because you need to achieve 90/95/100% code coverage due to some contract. Depending on your needs and reason, you will find your answer ;) You do not need to verify a constant, unless the constant can be user-defined. You do not need to mantain a "return 5" unless you can change it in future to throw an exception and break something enlse. You have to have test for those if you need 100% coverage.. and so on.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein: actually, as one of others, I agree unless 100% is a target :)

Comment: Yes, you should write tests for all three derived classes. That would reveal the mistake in the code that's shown above.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a comment, but an important thought came to me afterwards.

You say that there are 3 implementations of that interface.

What does that interface state? When you have more than one implementation, there's a high probability that **just implementing** that interface is not enough to be "ok". Does that interface implicitly **needs** something to be hold?

Your exemplar interface returns characters. Can those characters be any? Can it be \0 (null-char, end-of-string)? can it be \xFF (common EOF character)? Can it be ąęćźń (non-plain ASCII characters with 8th bit set that depend on codepage)? Are they allowed to throw exceptions?

If the interface imposes **any** such restrictions, you could/should/may test the implementations whether they really adhere to that interface's requirements.

Mind that I do not say to test the implementations against their inner workings. Inner workings say that's a constant. I say to verify that they successfully implement the interface's requirements. If the sole point of those classes is to implement that interface and provide data, you may check if that data *is valid*. Half a year later, you may change that data classes and step out of the valid domain, even if it's constant. You may change return 'c' to return '\xcc' which might be not acceptable.

But, as last note, remember to not over-do things. Testing is a tool, not a goal. If there are no requirements, then there's nothing to test, regardless of the implementation being clean or dirty. Always use proper tools for effects you need!

Comment: I absolutely agree, at least you'll need to test usage of these implementations via the interface.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In conjunction with the comments, it  becomes 
a good help to figure out is there a need for testing of certain methods